# Show that $\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}ka_k=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\sum_{i=k+1}^{+\infty}a_i$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Let $(a_k)_{k\in\Bbb{N}}$ a family of positive real.
>   Show that $$\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}ka_k=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\sum_{i=k+1}^{+\infty}a_i$$

So far, I have :

By definition $$\sum_{i=k+1}^{+\infty}a_i=\lim_{N\rightarrow+\infty}\sum_{i=k+1}^{N}a_i.$$

Then I tried to use inequality to switch the double sums. We have $k+1\le i\le N$
and $0 \le k\le (?)$ so we have 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\sum_{i=k+1}^{+\infty}a_i=\sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{i-1}a_i=\sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}ia_i
$$

I not convinced I have proved the result rigorously, right?

Comment: Fubini-Tonelli.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}ka_k = \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\sum_{l = 1}^k a_k$$.

By the fact $ \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\sum_{l = 1}^k = \sum_{l=1}^{+\infty}\sum_{k=l}^{+\infty}$, we get

$$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\sum_{l = 1}^k 1 a_k = \sum_{l=1}^{+\infty}\sum_{k=l}^{+\infty} a_k$$.

Comment: Thank you but as you can read my question is more about how do you prove your 'fact'?

Comment: @MarcGato You can treat the double summations as two different ways of counting all the positive integer pairs under the diagonal line. As since all terms are positive, the order of summation doesn't change the limit.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{i=k+1}^\infty a_i
=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \lbrace a_{k+1} + a_{k+2} + a_{k+3} + ... \rbrace
$$
$$
=\lbrace a_{1} + a_{2} + a_{3} + ... \rbrace +
\lbrace a_{2} + a_{3} + a_{4} + ... \rbrace +
\lbrace a_{3} + a_{4} + a_{5} + ... \rbrace +...
$$

$$
=0a_0+a_1+2a_2+3a_3+4a_4...
$$

$$
=\sum_{k=0}^\infty ka_k
$$