# Show that $\sum_i ia_i$ converges iff $\sum_i (s-s_i)$ converges.

Tags: sequences-and-series

The problem is: show that, if $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_i = s$, where $a_i$ are positive and real numbers, that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} ia_i$ converges if and only if $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} (s-s_i)$ also converges, where $s_i$ is the $i$th partial sum of $a_k$.

I started with the first direction. Assume  $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} ia_i$ converges to $l$. Then for $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $i > N$ such that (rearranging the assumption)
$$|\sum_{k=1}^{k=i-1} (s_i -s_k) -l| < \epsilon$$
which can be rearranged to 
$$
|\sum_{k=1}^{k = i -1} (s - s_k) - l - \sum_{k=1}^{k=i-1}(s - s_i)| < \epsilon
$$
and, using $|a -b| \geq |a| - |b|$, is
$$
|\sum_{k=1}^{k = i -1} (s - s_k) - l| - \sum_{k=1}^{k=i-1}|(s - s_i)| < \epsilon
$$
so what remains is to show that $\lim_{i \to \infty}|s-s_i|(i-1) = 0$, but there seems to be no reason for that to be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we can omit taking absolute value, as $s > s_i$.

Then we have $(s - s_i) \cdot (i - 1) = \sum\limits_{j=i}^\infty a_j \cdot (i - 1) < \sum\limits_{j=i}^\infty a_j \cdot j$. And this is the remainder of $\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty a_i \cdot i$, so it indeed goes to $0$.

For the other direction, we can use that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^n (s - s_k) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n + 1} i \cdot a_i - \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n+1} a_i + \sum\limits_{i=n}^\infty n\cdot a_i = 
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n + 1} i \cdot a_i - \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n+1} a_i + n \cdot (s - s_n)
$

And as $s - s_n$ monotonically decreases, if $\sum s - s_n$ converges then $n \cdot (s - s_n) \to 0$.

I think there should be some elegant rearrangement to prove both directions simultaneously, but I can't think of any.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/937882/show-that-sum-k-0-inftyka-k-sum-k-0-infty-sum-i-k1-inftya?rq=1 Probably a duplicate question I missed.